# How can I check with if my site is running?

Tags: drush

Is there a way with Drush or something else to check if a specified Drupal site is still up and running, means fully normal functioning, after automated maintenance/updating in an external script?

Sometimes an update can fail in a script and then there is a none-functional site left. I want to detect that situation. So have a command and the output is the status of the site?  E.g.

```bash
drush <command> <site>
```

yields down/up or something.

The `drush status` command doesnt seemed to have such functionality.

### Edit

When I was searching for the tools suggested in the comments I see that i was unspecific in the beginning, sorry for that. I mean the script is updating Drupal core and modules via Composer and Drush e.g.

```bash
~/bin/composer.phar update drupal/core "drupal/core-*" --with-all-dependencies
drush updatedb -l $WEBSITENAME
drush cache:rebuild
```

So I don't speak about updating whole servers and systems, just automated updating Drush, core and modules.

Comment: How do you define "up and running"?

Comment: @Jaypan That's exactly what I was going to ask. Drush doesn't "know" anything about the web server as far as I know.

Comment: @Jaypan i tried to make my question clearer in that respect

Comment: Health checks should be performed by an external system

Comment: This is a better suited task to server monitoring / healthcheck apps.

Comment: @Clive what do you mean by this?

Comment: Find a service which will ping your site every x seconds and report/notify a non-200 response. Drush is a command line tool, so asking it to detect whether your site, a stateless http application, is up, is a losing battle

Comment: @Kevin thanks for the hint, i think that is the external system Clive suggested?

Comment: At the time I write this comment, the question is "Is there a way with drush or something else to check if a specified drupal site is still up and running...". Yes, there are a great many ways to check if any website is up and running. But that's not a Drupal question.

Comment: ok, thanks for the advice, i check out some of the hints in the comments.

Comment: I use Uptime Robot myself: https://uptimerobot.com/

Comment: Pingdom, New Relic, just to name a few... there are dozens if not hundreds.

Comment: @Jaypan i see that i was really unspecific with my question so i tried to refine it with an edit.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest definition of a running site is that it returns a status code 200. From the command line or a script, you could use wget or curl.

If you want to avoid these tools a Drush only solution would be using the built-in guzzle client:

```
drush ev "echo Drupal::httpClient()->head('www.example.com')->getStatusCode();"
```